# Does counting with fingers diminish the ability to work with numbers in the future for children?

Tags: children, mathematics

There is a belief that says children who count with the aid of their fingers will be [prone to having problems in math in the later years to come](http://www.mathsinsider.com/no-no-no-no-dont-let-your-child-finger-count/).
Is this belief true?

Comment: I added a claim from the interwebs backing this up.

Comment: Can we actually provide figures on the numbers of children who don't count with their fingers? I'm guessing that would be incredibly close to zero.

Comment: I always use me fingers for multiplying a small number by *n* - 1 in base *n*...

Comment: I expect that there is a correlation, but I don't think it's causal. Probably weaker math students count on their fingers longer and are more likely to develop problems with math. Anecdote: I counted on my fingers right up to high school and went to college (undergrad/grad) for mathematics and did fine.